# Import XML Apple Music Playlist in iTunes

Tags: itunes, apple-music

I have exported from iTunes the XML of a playlist followed on Apple Music (I have an active subscription Apple Music).

Now I want to reimport it again so, I do that in iTunes, sync iCloud Library, getting covers... But can't play tracks in the playlist anymore. When i look at the infos of the track you can see that :

[image]

The issue is the kind "internet audio stream" instead of "Apple Music AAC audio file" so that's probably why the "iCloud" status is in error.

So how can I do to be able to play again this Playlist ?

Thanks